# Parallel container - synchronize on element erasure

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I use a `Concurrency::concurrent_unordered_map` successfully in my program (this is an implementation made by Microsoft). This is needed because multiple inserts/updates for elements and quite rare deletes are performed in a concurrent manner.

I know that this container (like all other concurrent containers) provides an unsafe `erase()` method - for erasing a node.

What would you think would be the best approach to make the erase process also thread safe ? This happens rarely as I've said (only because user intervention) and I would not like so much to have a critical section that has to be entered every time I perform a search on the container (or for that matter any other operations like iterator traversal and node updates). What do you think? I was also thinking on an event based mechanism but I don't see how this is applicable here.

Comment: Lock the section with a mutex, erase from the container, unlock.

Comment: The only problem with the mutex is that it seems that I have to include in the same mutex all other updates that are made on the container: so all the inserts, iterator traversal, updates on the elements have to be guarded by the same mutex. I'd rather prefer another solution

Comment: Well, you'll have to wrap the erase function into some `sync_erase()`, and guarantee that clients *only* call that function. Then you put the mutex only in there.

Comment: But then I will have to put sync_erase() also in functions like: iter FindElement(key); InsertElement(key, value); UpdateElement(iter, value) ... basically seems like every operation that touches the concurrent container should be guarded. Do we really need this or is there something more clever than this ?

Comment: I was thinking on one hand on the cost of entering an exclusive section (mutex) on one hand - which presumably should be lower as long as the section was not already locked by another thread; but all this seems to make the solution quite awkard

Comment: I'm not sure (and I'm not familiar with the class), but associative containers are *very* hard to write lock-free, perhaps even impossible. So you *will* have to use mutexes to synchronise some operations. Awkward, yes, but inevitable. Read the documentation carefully to find out what's guaranteed to work lock-free and what isn't.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at lock free hash tables? Check http://erdani.com/publications/cuj-2004-10.pdf & http://erdani.com/publications/cuj-2004-12.pdf , although I wouldn't go down this path unless I could find a stable one available already.

Comment: @Ylisar Thanks for the links.And you are right, I would not go (for now at least) down this path for the moment. I was mostly looking for a solution on what I have already available.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Actually Concurrency::concurrent_unordered_map is a hash based container.

Comment: @Ghita: I'm aware of that. I do believe however that lock-free hash containers are a very complicated data structure, and I think I recall that you *cannot* implement them in principle without a garbage collector. What I'm suspecting is that MS is giving you a restricted version of the structure that only allows certain operations in a lock-free manner, while allowing others (like `erase`) only in an unsafe manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the involvement of a critical section to make the erase process concurrent safe defeats the purpose of using a concurrent container at all in my case. If one would use such an approach every operation that relates to the concurrent container would have to be guarded by the same lock (i.e. operations that until now wouldn't have had to step on each others toe now have to wait on the same critical section). So this is by far the worst idea that  renders your concurrent container useless in every situation that you might use it.

An idea that addresses the mentioned inconveniences would be to use a Reader Writer lock. This allows shared reads but exclusive writes. One should protect the deletes with a writer lock and every other operation on the map with a reader lock like this:

```
    InsertOperation(key) -- this inserts the key in case is not present (and constructs a default constructed value)
    {
       reader_writer_lock::scoped_lock_read guard(reader_writer_lock);
       ...
    }

    value Find(key)
    {
        reader_writer_lock::scoped_lock_read guard(reader_writer_lock);
        ...
     }

     void EraseElement(key)
     {
        reader_writer_lock::**scoped_lock** guard(reader_writer_lock);
        ...
     }
```

Comment: Actually yes, in the sense that traversal, iterator access, inserts are all concurrent safe in this container

Comment: @Dani. I've corrected the Insert signature, because what it actually does is to insert a key/value in the hash container in case the key is not present

Comment: I was refering to the implementation of this container from : http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/concrtextras/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5189

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that should work quite all right I think would be to fire an Event when entering `EraseElement(key)` and resetting at procedure finish. This way every other operation would have to wait on that event before proceeding. I think that this would likely offer the same level of performance as my previous solution.

Answer (score 0):

And another article on the subject of concurrent data structures: 
[Lock-Free Data Structures with Hazard Pointers](http://drdobbs.com/184401890) by Andrei Alexandrescu and Maged Michael